# requirejs define: nested dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'd like to define A, but A should require B and B require C (for the sake of r.js)

Any of the these two are correct?

```
define([
    'module'
], function(module) {
    require(['C'], function() {
        require(['B'], function() {

            var A;

            return A;
        });
    });
});


require(['C'], function() {
    require(['B'], function() {
        define([
            'module'
        ], function(module) {
            var A;

            return A;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of your choices are correct.

You first choice attempts to use `return` to return a value from an asynchronous callback. It is generally not possible, and RequireJS is no different. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and its answers for why it is that way.

Your second choice puts a `define` inside a callback passed to `require`. This may work in some toy cases but in general this just won't work. (By "toy case" I mean proof-of-concepts where all conditions are under tight control. Such cases do not reflect the realities of real applications.)

[Linh Pham's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29385297/1906307) is really your option here:

```
define(["module", "B", "C"], function(module){
    var A;

    return A;
});
```

And if `B` depends on `C` and is not a AMD library, put a shim for it. In a comment you objected that you'd have to have "hundreds" of shims if you did this. You have a few options to avoid these shims:

1. Do not load `C` with RequireJS. Load it with a `script` element before RequireJS is loaded on your page.
2. Design your application to be started with just one module and require that your application be started by loading `C` before anything else:

   ```
   require(['C'], function () {
       require(['main']);
   });
   ```

   `main` would be the module that starts your application. The disadvantage of this method is that if you are like me, eventually, you are going to forget to require `C` before you require `main`.

Comment: or simply use `deps: ["C", "main"]` in `require.config` _(note: `deps` at the same level with `shim`, `path` or `baseUrl`... etc..)_, I think this should be short and clearer.

Comment: @LinhPham `deps: ["C"]` is *asynchronous*. There is no point in time by which it is guaranteed that `C` will be loaded. So if you adapt my last example to use `deps:["C"]` instead of `require(['C'], ...` chances are that `require(['main'])` will execute *before* `C` is loaded.

Comment: That is very useful info, so in order to use `deps: ["C", "main"]` I will need to config `shim` for `main` module like: `shim:{ "main" : ["C"] }` right?

Comment: Yes, if `main` happens to be a non-AMD module. I did not state it explicitly in my answer but `main` should be an AMD module since it is created for the application developed by the OP.

Comment: Your second option is what I adapted.

Answer (score 1):

just put deps inside define block, like this:

```
define(["module", "B", "C"], function(module){
    var A;

    return A;
});
```

If your module `B` depend on `C` then you should config it in your `require.config` like following

```
shim: {
    "B": ["C"] // shorthand of "B": {deps: ["C"]}
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea. Unfortunately I can't use it. C is like a library module, and I should add hundreds of shim configs if I use this.

Comment: you mean that `C` will be used globally, and all the modules depend on it?

Comment: C is not global, but it is required by so many modules so I won't attempt to list them all in shim config.